# iphone core data:Unable to Delete data with one to many relationship

Tags: iphone

I am new on core data and found one issue. I have two classes A and B with relationship One to Many (multiple B object can refer to one A object).

A<--->>B

I want to execute Delete query of ManagedObjectContext with some certain criteria, but I am unable to delete. It might be issue of Delete Relationship Rule (Deny, No Action, Nullify and Cascade) and I tried certain combination of it. But I am unable to Delete them.

Here is the same code which I mean to execute:-

```
for (A *value in allDeleteObject)
{
  NSError *error;
  for (B *objB in [value.BDetails allObjects])
  {
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:objB];
    [value removeGodetailsObject:objB];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
  } 
}
```

Please do tell me, if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (A *value in allDeleteObject)
{
  NSError *error;
  NSArray *array = [value.BDetails allObjects];
  for (B *objB in array)
  {
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:objB];
    [value removeGodetailsObject:objB];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
  } 
}
```

and use cascade delete rule at A and nullify at B.

Screen shot of Model:-

[image]

Comment: did u tried the code that i changed and by the way what problems you are getting.

Comment: Ya i also did this change...my problem is I am unable to delete object and its relation. Even in printing error description I only get Class Object as description.

Comment: I've added snapshot of it...i guess you will get it...as per you said, i set 'godetails' to cascade and 'gotofeat' as nullify